# XML Get Value from Node C#

Tags: c#, xml

I am new to c# and I am struggling to work out how to get a value from a some xml I have serialized into a class.

I built the class using xsd as explained in a thread I found on stack.

Can anyone help me get to the value for LoginState please?

This is what I can see when I debug...

[image]

This is the class I am serializing it into:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace vCreate.Model
{
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class NewDataSet
{

    private object[] itemsField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Table", typeof(NewDataSetTable), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Table1", typeof(NewDataSetTable1), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public object[] Items
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class NewDataSetTable
{

    private string loginStateField;

    private string loginMessageField;

    private string authIDField;

    private string userIDField;

    private string companyIDField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string LoginState
    {
        get
        {
            return this.loginStateField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.loginStateField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string LoginMessage
    {
        get
        {
            return this.loginMessageField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.loginMessageField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string AuthID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.authIDField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.authIDField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string UserID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.userIDField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.userIDField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string CompanyID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.companyIDField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.companyIDField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class NewDataSetTable1
{

    private string languageIDField;

    private string languageDescriptionField;

    private string langLargeImageField;

    private string langThumbImageField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string LanguageID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.languageIDField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.languageIDField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string LanguageDescription
    {
        get
        {
            return this.languageDescriptionField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.languageDescriptionField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string LangLargeImage
    {
        get
        {
            return this.langLargeImageField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.langLargeImageField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string LangThumbImage
    {
        get
        {
            return this.langThumbImageField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.langThumbImageField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What **is** the issue you're having?

Comment: Just follow the tree you're looking at. `resultingMessage.Items[0].LoginState`

Comment: The value of `LoginState` is `1`.

Comment: as i see it you can do resultMessage.LoginState

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as we all understood what you need to do is `resultingMessage.Items[0].LoginState` to get the Login State and put it in an integer.

```
int state = (resultingMessage.Items[0] as NewDataSetTable).LoginState;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was expecting but it says 'object' does not contain a definition for 'LoginState' and no extension method 'LoginState' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly referenc?)

Comment: @TrevorDaniel i've edit the answer. now that the question is more understandable have my +1

Comment: brilliant! - that worked a treat! - sad that ive been given a -2 already for my question :(

Comment: @TrevorDaniel your question wasn't understood. if you would have written as you said to me that you tried and got that error in the original question you would have probably get +4 instead of -2

Answer (score 1):

Now you have deserialized the XML, all you have to do is fetch it from Dataset. Try following

```
foreach (DataTable table in resultingMessage.Tables)
{
   foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
   {
     foreach (object item in row.ItemArray)
     {
        // read item
        var loginState = item.LoginState;
     }
   }
}
```